# Is it important to equalize the minimum price fluctuation in pairs trading?

Tags: futures, pairs-trading

For example, suppose we were trading a strategy which buys one [Brent](https://www.theice.com/products/219/Brent-Crude-Futures) contract and sells one [Gasoil](https://www.theice.com/products/909/Gasoil-Futures) contract. The minimum price fluctuation for a Brent contract is \$10, and the minimum price fluctuation for Gasoil is \$25, although the contract price for each is on the same order of magnitude. I have heard that the spread should be priced to take this discrepency into consideration, but I'm not sure I see how or why.

Comment: I am not sure you need to account for the contract tick size, but you definitely need to account for differing variance or 'beta' of the two contracts.

Comment: @experquisite Can you elaborate on this or give a link to something I can read? This is interesting. My general strategy has been to do a linear regression regression on two price series to find a ratio, but I haven't considered heterogeneous variances.

Comment: If your basket only has two contracts, then a linear regression on prices is fine.  Some people attempt to trade the "ratio" of two prices, though, or trade flat 1:1 contracts, which is usually a mistake.  There is always some debate whether one should be regressing prices or log-prices.